# Failed to build build_runner:build_runner

Tags: flutter, build-runner

I am receiving the following error message when I run:

> flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZdd6.png)

I tried:
flutter clean

> flutter pub cache repair
> flutter pub run build_runner clean

and then

> flutter pub run build_runner build

Please, help me fix it

Comment: My guess is that you are missing imports, what does the dart analysis say?

Comment: this is the first time i got this error this is analysis import 'package:analyzer/src/clients/dart_style/rewrite_cascade.dart';